# Visual Studio application deployment and external libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deployment, dependencies, libraries

I'm currently developing a program that uses two external libraries - OpenSSL and SDL2 - and I'm still a little wet behind the ears when it comes to software development. I'm planning on having my app run on both Windows and Mac and I am wondering about the process behind the installation of external dependencies on another machine.

First of all, when I come to deploy my application in Visual Studio, will Visual Studio export those external dependencies/libraries to the output release folder along with my application? If not, how do I have my application install those dependencies on another machine?

Secondly, is it best to build those libraries within, or adjacent to, my project folders, or can they be anywhere on my computer and I just point Visual Studio to them and Visual Studio does the rest?

Any relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could use two tools: depends.exe/ProcessExplorer and InstallShield.

depends.exe/ProcessExplorer is used to check the dll and lib used. InstallShield is used to deploy .exe.

For example:

In ProcessExplorer, you can see the third-party libraries needed for the program PointCloudUI2.0.exe to run.
[image]

Then, you could add the corresponding directories and files in the Application Files, this can add the corresponding dependent DLL.

[image]

Also, you could refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2019#create-an-installer-package-windows-desktop) for more informantion.